# In .Net MVCGrid I'm unable to pass additional query options using client side bindings

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvcgrid.net

Hi I have a grid that I need to send values to the RetrieveDataMethod. I am using 2 drop down menus like filters but because the menus don't relate directly to the columns in my grid I can't use the filter option.

I really like the Idea of using the client side binding because it is clean and avoids me needing to write any jquery.

The code for my grid is

```
public static MVCGridBuilder<Batch> BuildGrid(GridDefaults gridDefaults, ColumnDefaults columnDefaults)
    {
        return new MVCGridBuilder<Batch>(gridDefaults, columnDefaults)
            .AddColumns(cols =>
            {
                cols.Add("BatchId")
                    .WithHeaderText("Batch Id")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.BatchId.Trim());
                cols.Add("PartNumber").WithHeaderText("Part Number")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.PartNumber.Trim());
                cols.Add("AdjustedQty")
                    .WithHtmlEncoding(false)
                    .WithHeaderText("Adjusted Qty")
                    .WithValueExpression((p, c) => c.UrlHelper.Action("AdjustBatchQuantity", "Batch"))
                    .WithValueTemplate("<a href='#' id='AdjustedQty' style='display: inline;' data-type='text' data-pk='{Model.BatchId}' data-url='AdjustBatchQuantity' data-title='Adjust Quantity' class='editable editable-click' >{Model.AdjustedQty}</a>");
                cols.Add("UpdateDate")
                    .WithHeaderText("Update Date")
                    .WithValueExpression(p => p.UpdateDate.ToShortDateString());
            })
            .WithAdditionalQueryOptionNames("FamilyId", "ColorId")
            .WithAdditionalSetting("RenderLoadingDiv", true)
            .WithDefaultSortColumn("UpdateDate")
            .WithDefaultSortDirection(SortDirection.Dsc)
            .WithFiltering(true)
            .WithRetrieveDataMethod(context =>
            {
                var options = context.QueryOptions;

                var batchRepo = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IBatchRepository>();
                var productRepo = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IProductRepository>();

                int family = 0, bottleQty = 0, colorId = 0, count;

                if (options.AdditionalQueryOptions.ContainsKey("FamilyId"))
                {
                    var temp = options.GetAdditionalQueryOptionString("FamilyId");

                    if (temp != null)
                    {
                        family = int.Parse(options.GetAdditionalQueryOptionString("FamilyId"));
                    }
                }

                if (options.AdditionalQueryOptions.ContainsKey("ColorId"))
                {
                    var color = options.GetAdditionalQueryOptionString("ColorId");

                    if (color != null)
                    {
                        var temp = color.Split('_');

                        if (temp[0] != string.Empty)
                        {
                            colorId = Convert.ToInt32(temp[0]);
                        }

                        if (temp.Length > 1)
                        {
                            bottleQty = Convert.ToInt32(temp[1]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                var partNumbers = productRepo.GetPartNumbersByFamilyColorQuantity(family, colorId, bottleQty);
                var items = batchRepo.GetBatcheHistoryRecordsForGrid(options.GetLimitOffset(), options.GetLimitRowcount(), partNumbers, out count);

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(options.SortColumnName))
                {
                    switch (options.SortColumnName.ToLower().Replace(" ", string.Empty))
                    {
                        case "batchid":
                            items = items.OrderBy(p => p.BatchId).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "partnumber":
                            items = items.OrderBy(p => p.PartNumber).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "adjustedqty":
                            items = items.OrderBy(p => p.AdjustedQty).ToList();
                            break;
                        case "updatedate":
                            items = items.OrderBy(p => p.UpdateDate).ToList();
                            break;
                    }
                }

                if (options.SortDirection.ToString().ToLower() == "dsc")
                {
                    items.Reverse();
                }

                return new QueryResult<Batch>() { Items = items, TotalRecords = count };
            });
    }
```

And the relevant parts of my HTML are

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Areas/MfgTransactions_MVC/Scripts/CreateBatchDropDownFilters.js")

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/BootstrapGridScripts")
@Styles.Render("~/bundles/Bootstrap3/BootstrapGridCss");

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#AdjustedQty').editable();
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
        $.fn.editable.defaults.ajaxOptions = {
            ajaxOptions: {
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json'
            }
        };
    });
</script>

....

<div class="form-group ">
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FamilyId)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.FamilyId, Model.FamilyListItems, "Select Family", new { @class = "form-control", data_mvcgrid_type = "additionalQueryOption", data_mvcgrid_option = "FamilyId", data_mvcgrid_apply_additional = "change" })
 </div>

 <div class="form-group ">
     @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Color)
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Color, Model.ColorListItems, "Select Colour", new { @class = "form-control", data_mvcgrid_type = "additionalQueryOption", data_mvcgrid_option = "ColorId", data_mvcgrid_apply_additional = "change" })
 </div>
```

The problem seems to be that the additionalQueryOption event isn't been triggered. When I debug my code I can see that the line `var options = context.QueryOptions;` has the AdditionalQueryOptions but there are no values for them.

Is there a step that I have missed for setting this up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I had removed

```
@Scripts.Render("~/MVCGridHandler.axd/script.js")
```

and placed it in my bundle config, but it didn't seem to work there.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why it didn't work in the bundle?

Comment: Hi @MatthewGoulart I never looked into why it didn't work in the bundle.

Comment: It can't work in a bundle as it's generated on the fly by the axd. Only way is to download the file, save it and then you can bundle it. I haven't tried that yet.